# Is it possible to make responsive HTML page with Angular ngClass directive and bootstrap classes?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5

I want to be able to reduce the size of the buttons in my Angular application using bootstrap class btn-sm.

I want to write something like this:
`<button [ngClass]="{ 'btn-sm' : window.screen.width < '575.5px' }">Edit</button>`
Any other ideas except writing media query?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that, ngClass allows that.

First of all you need Bootstrap. Then add the bootstrap class and use the ngClass directive to conditionally apply additional classes based on certain conditions, a basic and common example for that:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" [ngClass]="{'col-lg-8': isLargeScreen}">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" [ngClass]="{'col-lg-4': isLargeScreen}">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8" [ngClass]="{'col-md-6': isMediumScreen, 'col-sm-12': isSmallScreen}">
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For the code you posted, it's an error, you gave to window.screen.width a string but needs a number type, example:

```
<button [ngClass]="{ 'btn-sm' : window.screen.width < 575.5 }">Edit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the .html of a component in Angular all the variables should be variables of the component. So to use the object "window" or the object "Math" you should write in your component.ts

```
window:any=window; 
Math:any=Math;
```

Personal opinion: It's not very "scalable" your approach to "hardcode" the ngClass in this way, the media querys are made to avoid this kind of "mix" html and .css